# OrientDB GraphED - SQL insert edge between two (select vertex RID)s? Or alternative approach for very large import

Tags: sql, graph-theory, orientdb, bulkinsert, vertices

For example, two simple vertices in an OrientDB Graph:

```
orientdb> CREATE DATABASE local:/databases/test admin admin local graph;       
Creating database [local:/databases/test] using the storage type [local]...
Database created successfully.
Current database is: local:/graph1/databases/test
orientdb> INSERT INTO V (label,in,out) VALUES ('vertexOne',[],[]);                                                                                                                 
Inserted record 'V#6:0{label:vertexOne,in:[0],out:[0]} v0' in 0.001000 sec(s).
orientdb> INSERT INTO V (label,in,out) VALUES ('vertexTwo',[],[]);
Inserted record 'V#6:1{label:vertexTwo,in:[0],out:[0]} v0' in 0.000000 sec(s).
```

Is there a way to create an edge between these two vertexes by only knowing their 'label's, not their 'RID's?

For example (doesn't work):

```
orientdb> INSERT INTO E (label, in, out) VALUES ('is_connected_to', (SELECT @rid FROM V WHERE label = 'vertexOne'), (SELECT @rid FROM V WHERE label = 'vertexTwo'));
Inserted record 'E#7:0{label:is_connected_to,in:null,out:null} v0' in 0.001000 sec(s).
```

I've tried 'FLATTEN' as a potential workaround.  No luck:

```
orientdb> INSERT INTO E (label, in, out) VALUES ('is_connected_to', (SELECT FLATTEN(@rid) FROM V WHERE label = 'vertexOne'), (SELECT FLATTEN(@rid) FROM V WHERE label = 'vertexTwo'));
Inserted record 'E#7:1{label:is_connected_to,in:null,out:null} v0' in 0.001000 sec(s).
```

The edges created are between `null` and `null`. No dice.

I was hoping to use OrientDB SQL for this since I have a very large import of connections and the SQL approach seems to be faster.

However, if this isn't possible, any suggestions about an alternative for batch importing edges (roughly 2M)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQLCreateEdge](http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/SQLCreateEdge) is probably what you're trying to do:

```
create edge from
(select from V where label = 'vertexOne')
to
(select from V where label = 'vertexTwo')
set label = 'is_connected_to'
```

however, for very large import of connections i suggest [SQLCreateLink](http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/SQLCreateLink). this gem is suggested [here](http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/ImportFromRDBMS).

Answer (score 0):

Bulk edge insert is possible as [SQL Bath](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-batch.html)

```
begin;
  CREATE EDGE E FROM #34:3349  TO #32:3349;
  CREATE EDGE E FROM #41:10971 TO #33:3348;
commit retry 100;
```