# OrientDB - Creating an edge using rid's from index queries

Tags: orientdb

I'm trying to create edges between existing vertices queried by their indexed IDs, similar to the first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940097/orientdb-graphed-sql-insert-edge-between-two-select-vertex-rids-or-alternat), but using [this](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/Indexes#lookup) index lookup query instead of the label query:

```
CREATE EDGE cite
FROM
(SELECT FROM index:<className>.<indexName> WHERE key = "<keyString>")
TO
(SELECT FROM index:<className>.<indexName> WHERE key = "<keyString>")
```

This gives me the following error: `com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OCommandExecutionException: Source vertex '#-1:-1' not exists`

Possibly relevant:

When I just query `SELECT FROM index:<className>.<indexName> WHERE key = "<keyString>"` by itself it returns an array object structured like:

```
[ { '@type': 'd',
    key: '<keyString>',
    rid: { cluster: <actual cluster>, position: <actual position> }
    @rid: { cluster: -1, position: -1 } } ]
```

I'm guessing that the error has something to do with the `CREATE EDGE` query using the `@rid` instead of the `rid` but I'm not sure.

The query successfully creates the edges if I simply use the `#<actual cluster>:<actual position>` instead of the `SELECT` subquery.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Edit: In the interest of replicability, I have the same problem in the GratefulDeadConcerts database when I (1) add a property `name` to the V class schema, (2) create a unique `nameIndex` index of V using the `name` property under V, and then (3) use the following query:
`create edge followed_by from (select from index:nameIndex where key = 'HEY BO DIDDLEY') to (select from index:nameIndex where key = 'IM A MAN')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you query the class directly?

```
CREATE EDGE cite
FROM
(select from Class where field = '<keyString>')
TO
(select from Class where field = '<keyString>')
```

Select from index return a temp document as result set with key,and rid

you can try but i don't know if it will work

```
SELECT expand(rid) FROM index:<className>.<indexName> WHERE key = "<keyString>"
```

Comment: Thanks, both of your suggestions work great. I think I tried something similar to your first suggestion initially but I couldn't get it working, which is why I ended up attempting to use the `index:` format.